# FireBase PhoneAuth INVALID_APP_CREDENTIAL:App validation failed Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I know people asked about it before, but I tried all that was suggested.

I'm trying to use PhoneAuth through firebase. Followed step by step, enabled phone Auth in my app, added SHA 1 and SHA 256 just in case, Linked my google account but still, when I try and send the phone number I always return to 
onVerificationFailed
With the error An internal error has occurred. `[ INVALID_APP_CREDENTIAL:App validation failed ]`.

Please any help would do. 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the SHA 1 of play store to firebase SHA1 and then link it. It works for me in case of signed build. Replace the new google-services.json file in your android app from the new one generated in firebase account after the sha1 key change.